# Azure CosmoDB has no option to set the scale mode even docs says so

Tags: azure, cloud

According to the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-container-throughput?tabs=dotnetv2

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/how-to-provision-autoscale-throughput.md#azure-cosmos-db-net-v3-sdk-for-sql-api

There should be an option to set the scale mode. Unfortunately, this is not the case which you can see in the screens.

[image: Edit container]
[image: Create new container]

So I'm wondering if they changed something and didn't update the docs or am I missing something?

I set the Capacity mode to Serverless.

Comment: My guess is that your account is configured to run in `Serverless` mode instead of `Provisioned` mode. Can you please check that?

Comment: Yes thats true, but I can't change the capacity mode or can I? Otherwise I have create a new ressource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The reason you're seeing this behavior is because you have configured your account to run in `Serverless` mode where there's no pre-configured throughput either at the database or container level. Throughput is adjusted automatically by Cosmos DB based on the usage.

> but I can't change the capacity mode or can I?

Unfortunately no. It is not possible to switch between `Serverless` and `Provisioned` model as of today. You will have to create a new Cosmos DB account with `Provisioned` model.